# switching to new user limits console capabilities

Tags: su, useradd

I'm creating a new user:

```
groupadd sybase
useradd -g sybase -d /opt/sybase sybase
passwd sybase
chown sybase:sybase /opt/sybase
chown sybase:sybase /var/sybase
```

then switch to this user:

```
su - sybase
```

than understand that the console-behavior is changed, tab is not working at all -for auto-completing, for example.

What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: you accepted it faster than I was finished editing >:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auto-complete (and history) is part of the `bash` shell. You can change to the `bash` shell for that user with.

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash $USER
```

Or for any other shell you like: change the `/bin/bash`.

---

From `man useradd`

> s, --shell SHELL
>
> The name of the user's login shell. The default is to leave this
>              field blank, which causes the system to select the default login
>              shell specified by the SHELL variable in /etc/default/useradd, or
>              an empty string by default.

So you could have used:

```
useradd -g sybase -d /opt/sybase sybase -s /bin/bash
```

---

more /etc/default/useradd

```
# Default values for useradd(8)
#
# The SHELL variable specifies the default login shell on your
# system.
# Similar to DHSELL in adduser. However, we use "sh" here because
# useradd is a low level utility and should be as general
# as possible
SHELL=/bin/sh
```